# Deploying to Azure API Management with GIT but doing something similar to web.config transformations

Tags: git, transformation, azure-api-management

I am currently working on deploying AZURE API Management configurations to multiple servers. Like DEV / TEST / PROD for example.

So I can clone my repository using GIT for say my DEV environment. But I might want to push this to TEST using the same "code". I mean, I would not have a TEST specific whole version of the code but 1* code base that I could transform some variables for my TEST deployment.

So a Url would go from this:
http://my-DEV-url.com
to
http://my-TEST-url.com

[image]

Now in other worlds like websites, for example, I can transform my web.config using web.test.config. SO depending on my build config my config gets automatically transformed.

So my real question here is, can I do any funky transforms on my Azure API Management json to avoid having to keep 3 versions (DEV/TEST/PROD) of my code in 3 different GIT branches.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [properties](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-properties/) to define instance-scoped values. Properties can't be used to define serviceUrl for an API, but you can use [set-backend-service policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/7406a8ce-5f9c-4fae-9b0f-e574befb2ee9#SetBackendService) to define serviceUrl in runtime.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
         <set-backend-service base-url="{{backend-url}}" />
         ....
```

Then you set "backend-url" property to desired values on your APIM instances.
Note that Properties are not exported via git, so all your instances will have different values.

Comment: Thanks @j.j.  I actually found this yesterday. Works great. Thanks